# Agregar un metodo a la class Array JavaScripts

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría saber como agregar un método a la class array en JavaScript.

Por ejemplo estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo que hace `push`, pero con el nombre de `anadir`.

Aquí les dejo el código que creo q seria el camino pero no lo consigo.

```
Array.prototype.anadir = function(objeto){
    
    push(objeto);

};

var elemento = [1, 2, 33, 4,];
var arreglo = new Array(elemento);
arreglo.anadir(2);
console.log(arreglo);
```

Muchas Gracias de antemano por tu tiempo un abrazo.

Comment: `push` por si solo no existe. Cambia `push` por `this.push`. ¿Porqué? Simplemente porque `this` hace referencia a tu Array creado con `new` el cual, por herencia, dispone del método `anadir` que has creado y de todos los otros métodos de Array. Saludos

Answer (score 4):

Si lo quisieras hacer como pensabas, tienes que saber que el array original está en `this`, es el contexto de `prototype`:

```js
Array.prototype.añadir = function(...objeto) {
  this.push(...objeto);
};

let arreglo = [1];

arreglo.añadir(2);

arreglo.añadir(3,4,5,6);

console.log(arreglo);
```

Comment: Eso mismo, ando desde el móvil y responder es un poco difícil, pero me quitaste el comentario. Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias, justo eso, sabes de algun documento o pagina que pueda aprender mas sobre esto?

Comment: @JrFullStack Podes empezar leyendo este artículo [Herencia y la cadena de prototipos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Answer (score 0):

Si la idea es que `anadir` sea idéntico a `push`, entonces basta con igualarlo a dicho método.

**Ejemplo:**

```js
Array.prototype.anadir = Array.prototype.push;

var elemento = [1, 2, 33, 4, ];
var arreglo = new Array(elemento);
arreglo.anadir(2);
console.log(arreglo);
```

Comment: Sería bueno saber el porque del voto negativo...

Comment: Ateniéndose estrictamente a la pregunta, esta es la mejor respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Marcos, otra forma mas de hacerlo, un millón de gracias